# Strange border on IMG tag

Tags: html, css, border, image

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>

<header>
    <img class="logo" />
</header>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border:none;
}

img.logo {
    width:126px;
    height:50px;
    background-image:url('images/logo.png');
}
```

One way or another everytime i try to style an IMG like this a strange border appears. Even if I would place border:0px; or border:none; in the img.logo css the border remains.

Comment: `<img>` tags need a `src`.

Comment: This is not valid html.  src and alt are [required attributes for the image tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_img.asp)

Comment: That explains a lot thanks. The reason I used the IMG tag is because i find it the most logical tag for an image and it doesnt need a close tag.

Comment: IMG is still the most logical tag for displaying an image that ***is content*** and not decoration (aka presentation). If your document still makes sense without the image, CSS is preferred. You may want to use an [image replacement technique](http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/) or just use a transparent .png of the logo in an IMG tag, in addition to a background.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It's the default "special" border that appears when you use an `img` element with an a `src` attribute set to something that doesn't exist (or no `src` at all).

A common workaround is to set the `src` to a [`blank.gif` file](http://www-cdr.stanford.edu/~petrie/blank.gif):

```
<img class="logo" src="blank.gif" />
```

I have to point out that it (in this case) makes no sense to use an `<img>` with `background-image`. Just set the `src` attribute and forget about `background-image`.

Comment: I have never heard of this and can't reproduce it. Can you possibly give a reference, or is this browser specific?

Comment: Different browsers do behave differently with this. Look at this in Chrome or IE8, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/6LtfP/ Irritatingly, the `blank.gif` I linked to doesn't seem to be transparent. I had to find another version.

Comment: Wow that is quite interesting, thanks for sharing that. I was aware that FF needs the `-moz-force-broken-image-icon` to get the icon, but I've never seen how it can be affected in other browsers by using a blank src VS a non existent src VS no src attribute. IE has two icons, which I've never seen, and Chrome didn't display a border on the one with no src attr. Very interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You can Simply Use `div` instead of `img` for background image , if you are not going to use `src` attribute anywhere.

```
<div class="logo"> </div>
```

otherwise `src` is required.

Answer (score 3):

Combining [@thirtydot's answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5743100/508537) with [@Layke's answer for Smallest data URI image possible for a transparent image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13139830/508537), here is an all-in-one solution:

```
<img class="logo"
  src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
img {
  text-indent: -999px;
}
```

Comment: that just moves it away, so if your screen is a 4k you still see it but in a different place :) perhaps add some additional 0000 there

Comment: something like -200vw

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but now the border does not appear.

**Solution:**

Add following in the img tag in HTML

- src=""
- border="0"