# Removing the image border in Chrome/IE9

Tags: css, image, google-chrome, stylesheet, border

I am trying to get rid of the thin border that appears for every image in Chrome & IE9.
I have this CSS:

```
outline: none;
border: none;
```

Using jQuery, I also added a `border=0` attribute on every image tag. But the border as shown in the image still appears. Any solution?

```css
body {
    font: 10px "segoe ui",Verdana,Arial,sans-serif, "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Grande", Lucida, sans-serif;
}
img, a img {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}
.icon {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    text-indent: -99999px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -48px -144px;
    background-image: url(theme/images/ui-icons_0078ae_256x240.png);
    margin-right: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Dashboard <img class="icon" border="0"></h1>
```

See attached screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: "But the border as shown in the image still appears." Is there a screenshot?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I see the actual issue.  Your screen shot shows some dashes under the word Dashboard, but those dashes look an awful lot like they are actually part of the icon you are displaying.  If that's true, CSS/Javascript/Whatever isn't going to help.  You'll need to modify the actual image.

Comment: @ChrisLively I think he means the border around the question mark

Comment: I found the following solution more elegant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743083/strange-border-on-img-tag

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Instead of `border: none;` or `border: 0;` in your CSS, you should have:

```
border-style: none;
```

You could also put this in the image tag like so:

```
<img src="blah" style="border-style: none;">
```

Either will work unless the image has no `src`. The above is for those nasty link borders that show up in some browsers where borders refuse to play nice. The thin border that appears when there is no `src` is because chrome is showing that in fact no image exists in the space that you defined. If you are having this issue try one of the following:

- Use a `<div>` instead of an `<img>` element (effectively creating an element with a background image is all you are doing anyway, the `<img>` tag really isn't being used)
- If you want/need an `<img>` tag use Randy King's solution below
- Define an image `src`

Comment: This fix didn't work for me on the latest version of Chrome, however Randy King's fix did work. Thanks!

Comment: hmm.. I have the latest version of chrome and haven't seen this not work if it is not being overwritten by something a stylesheet. Randy King's solution will definitely work no matter what and is great for images that you will use often on the website but it is a pain to write it for every image. I do not think that chrome puts a border by default because if I have a html file with an image I cannot get an "unintentional" border to show up no matter what I wrap it in. Makes me feel like it is a css rule somewhere in one of your stylesheets that you need to get rid of or overwrite

Comment: not saying I am for sure correct haha.. just extremely curious

Comment: This is my jsFiddle quick test. View it in Chrome (obviously) :)
http://jsfiddle.net/darkkevind/vtNTa/

Comment: Ahh yup, I was a little off on what was being asked. If you set an image src it will go away but can I suggest using a div instead of an img here? It will work the same if you are trying to fill that space with a background image. What was the application for having an img tag with no src? alt/title tags?

Comment: actually alt tags wont work on an image tag with no src so I guess I would suggest a using a div with a background image or just adding a src to the image.

Comment: The reason for it being an IMG element was because if (in the result set of a search) there was no image to assign to the src yet it applied a class to the background which mapped to an icon (file type icon) in a png sprite.
I think the dev was trying to use the same element with this as he could have swapped out a DIV and an IMG element based on the result which would have been better...and easier...

Comment: Gotycha, Not sure how I got up votes on this but apparently it fixed a different issue for some people haha. I edited my answer.

Comment: I had a placeholder with no src.. fixed for me, tx!

Answer (score 56):

It's a Chrome bug, ignoring the "border:none;" style.

Let's say you have an image "download-button-102x86.png" which is 102x86 pixels in size. In most browsers, you would reserve that size for its width and height, but Chrome just paints a border there, no matter what you do.

So you trick Chrome into thinking that there is nothing there - size of 0px by 0px, but with exactly the right amount of "padding" to allow for the button. Here is a CSS id block that I am using to accomplish this...

```
#dlbutn {
    display:block;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    outline:none;
    padding:43px 51px 43px 51px;
    margin:0 auto 5px auto;
    background-image:url(/images/download-button-102x86.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Voila! Works everywhere and gets rid of the outline/border in Chrome.

Comment: This is what actually gets to the bottom of the problem. Thanks

Comment: Helped a ton, I didn't realize I could use this method until I made my own, not as good solution.

Comment: I noticed a tiny little box still showing up (Almost not visible) when using this method. It's a 1x1 border that is still there. When looking closely, does anyone else still see this, using this method? & What would be the fix for this?

Comment: @aaron-coding - yes I see this too. however I think that @randy-king has the correct solution - I have modified it slight to use with generic classes ```.borderFix {
 display: block;
 width: 1px !important;
 height: 1px !important;
 outline: none;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: -4px;
 background-image:none !important;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}```

Comment: @arron-coding: In my situation,  'overflow: hidden' was needed in addition to the other settings in order to get rid of the small box in Chrome.

Answer (score 19):

For anyone who wants to get rid of the border when the src is empty or there is no src just use this style:

```
IMG[src=''], IMG:not([src])      {opacity:0;}
```

It will hide the IMG tag completely until you add a src

Comment: This fix is fantastic for Chrome when lazy loading images. Thank you!

Comment: Great answer, upvoted. If you also want to show your placeholder image while it is loading, you can checkout my answer, I used some of the code from here.

Answer (score 6):

Add attribute border="0" in the img tag

Comment: Thanks. But I am already doing that using jQuery. Pl see the second line of the code snippet, where the img tag already has a border="0" attribute

Answer (score 4):

If u didn't define a src or the src attribute is empty in a img tag most browsers will create a border. To fix this use transparent image as src:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAMAAAAoyzS7AAAAA1BMVEX///+nxBvIAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAlwSFlzAAALEgAACxIB0t1+/AAAAApJREFUeJxjYAAAAAIAAUivpHEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" border="0">
```

Comment: this gif is a tad bit shorter data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to fix the Chrome Bug on loading images, but you ALSO want your placeholder image to load use (with Lazy Loading images, for example) use can do this trick:

```
.container { overflow: hidden; height: 200px; width: 200px }

.container img { width: 100%; height: 100% }

.container img[src=''],
.container img:not([src]) {
  width: 102%;
  height: 102%;
  margin: -1%;
}
```

This will make the border be hidden in the container's overflow and you won't see it.

Turn this: [image: Chrome border bug]

Into this: [image: Chrome border bug fixed]

Comment: It's a very nice fix, if both opacity and width/height can't be set to 0.

Answer (score 2):

I liked Randy King's solution in that chrome ignores the "border:none" styling, but its a bit complex to understand and it doesn't work in ie6 and older browsers. Taking his example, you can do this:

css:

```
ins.noborder
{
    display:block;
    width:102px;
    height:86px;
    background-image:url(/images/download-button-102x86.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

html

```
<ins class="noborder"></ins>
```

Make sure when you use the ins tag to close it off with a "" or else the formatting will look funky.

Comment: awesome solution. thanks for thinking that one up - works. I did make one change: `display: inline-block;` My tag is <icon src="..." />

Answer (score 1):

In your img src tag, add a border="0", for example, `<img src="img.jpg" border="0">` as per explained by @Amareswar above

Comment: Thanks. But I am already doing that using jQuery. Pl see the second line of the code snippet, where the img tag already has a border="0" attribute

Comment: Thanks Amareswar. This is what you mean right? <img class="ui-icon ui-icon-help  icon ui-icon-blue" border="0"> Do I need to close the image tag or something?

Answer (score 1):

using border="0" is an affective way, but you will need to add this attribute for each image.

i used the following jQuery to add this attribute for each image as i hate this outlines and borders around images.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('img').each(function () {
            $(this).attr("border", "0");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

inline css

```
<img src="logo.png" style="border-style: none"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the border by setting text-indent to a very big number, but the alt of the image also be gone.
Try this

```
img:not([src]) {
    text-indent: 99999px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when displaying a .png-image in a div-tag. A thin (1 px I think) black line was rendered on the side of the image. To fix it, I had to add the following CSS style:  `box-shadow: none;`

Answer (score 0):

same as what @aaron-coding and @randy-king had - but just a more generic one to hide image border before they are loaded (i.e. with [lazy-load.js](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) or something

*(apparently I can't do a code block in my original comment)*

```
.lazy-load-borderFix {
  display: block;
  width: 1px !important;
  height: 1px !important;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: -4px;
  background-image:none !important;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix it using padding style:

```
#picture {
    background: url("../images/image.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.icon {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

The border is disappearing, while you are increasing padding value. Find your own value.

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me. It took days which made me crazy.

```
img.logo
{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:0px;
    outline:none;
    padding:43px 51px 43px 51px;
    margin:0 auto 5px auto;
}
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to set the outline style to none (i.e.) outline:none, it's work with Me

Answer (score 0):

First create an image type PNG transparent with photoshop in mini size.
Then in your class please add:

```
content:url("url of your blank png");
```

Answer (score -1):

That happens  because you are using an img tag with no src attribute. The solution is puting the image into a div. Something like that:

```
<style>
         div#uno{
            display:block;
            width: 351px;
            height: 500px;
            background: url(especificaciones1.png) no-repeat;

         }
         div#dos{
            display:block;
            width: 612px;
            height: 500px;
            background: url(especificaciones2.png) no-repeat;
         }

</style>
<div class="especificaciones">
   <div id="uno" class="imag1"></div>
   <div id="dos" class="imag2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sometimes an image *has* to be used with the img element. This answer does not help us needing to use an img element.