# Cant remove image border in ie9

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing the image border in Chrome/IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013071/removing-the-image-border-in-chrome-ie9)

There is a border around the image which is wrapped in blue. it is blue in color... I tried to follow a few solutions but the border image doesnt disappear.

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
   a {outline : none;}
   a img {outline : none;}
   img {border : 0;}
   a:active, a:focus 
   { 
     outline: none; 
     ie-dummy: expression(this.hideFocus=true);
    }
</style>
```

Here is my html markup:

```
<p style="margin-left: 39%;margin-top: 23px;">
     <a  href="<?php echo $review[0]['link']; ?>" 
         target="_blank" style="border: none;text-decoration: none;">
         <img style="border: none;" 
              src="Images/Review/button_register_for_free.png"/>
     </a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only rule you should need, notwithstanding any other styles you have, is to set no border on images.

You almost did that with:

```
img {border : 0;}
```

But it should be:

```
img {border : none;}
```

Comment: that didnt work...look at the html ,  in the style attribute

Comment: Here is an example in JS Fiddle - you'll see that there is no border around the image: http://jsfiddle.net/Sohnee/5CmRW/ - testing in IE 9.0.8112.16421. If you are still stuck - perhaps you have left out some style rules from your example. Perhaps you could create a JS Fiddle that shows the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers show a border around images inside a link, which you can remove using:

```
a img { border: none; }
```

You might also want to remove the underlining of the link, which would show up looking like a bottom border for the image:

```
a { text-decoration: none; }
```