# Removing <a> Outline in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, sass, outline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove outline Image link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814366/how-to-remove-outline-image-link)

I'm trying to remove the link outline in IE. It's really annoying and unsightly. I've tried several things. My CSS/SASS looks like this

```
a {
  outline: none;
  outline: 0;
   &:focus {
     outline: none;
     outline: 0;
   }
   &:active {
     outline: none;
     outline: 0;
   }
}
```

Anyone have any tips or tricks. I'm testing in IE9, so I'm maybe theres something special for that?

Comment: Are you referring to an outline of an image?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8984197/1217408

Comment: Please see http://www.outlinenone.com/

Comment: the duplicate link above refers to outlinenone.com, but does also include an IE9-specific solution, in case you're still desperate to "fix" it. But I would challenge you not to use it if at all possible.

Comment: It is a very similar question, however theres was poorly worded/tagged, ergo I could not find it. Anyhow, turns out that the outline was not acting on the <a> tag, but on a <span> tag. Doh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting rid of the outline of an image or other objects can be done like so:

```
border-style:none;
```