# How do I get rid of the default outline in the <img> tag?

Tags: html, css

```
<img class="image_cover" src = "" />

.image_cover {
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    border-style:none;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

I'm demonstrating it in a fiddle here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H4TNw/)

In Chrome Version 33.0.1750.152, I am seeing a box (border) over the `<img>` tag. I am trying to get rid off it.

I followed the input over here: [Removing the image border in Chrome/IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013071/removing-the-image-border-in-chrome-ie9), and set the `border`, `border-style`, and `box-shadow` attributes, but I still see the border around it.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Border has value "none" meanwhile outline can be set to "0"

Answer (score 4):

Chrome automaticaly renders a border to `img` tags with an empty `src` attribute.

A workaround would be placing a transparent png or gif in this image tag.

Answer (score 2):

CSS

```
img {
    Border: none;
}
```

try this and it should remove any default borders

Comment: Does not work. http://jsfiddle.net/H4TNw/10/

Comment: @Louis93 it works when you have an image placed in the SRC. This then prevents any borders appearing on any other browser round the img

Answer (score 1):

It is because you don't have a source specified.  Once you specify an SRC, this shouldn't be a problem any longer.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have mentioned the border is there because the SRC is empty. If the src wasn't empty you could change the border using `border:none`. However this is happening because of default browser behavior on an `<img>` tag with no src which is why `border:none` has no effect.

***If for whatever reason you want to have an empty src you could do this.. But I am not sure why you would want an image tag with no src***

```
<img class="image_cover" src="" />

.image_cover {
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    content: "";
}
```

**DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/krishollenbeck/H4TNw/8/

Comment: Nice fix. This was not thought of on the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

the outline shows up because you are not setting the `src` attribute to a valid image url.

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of the outline is accomplished by making it transparent.

```
img{    
    border-color:transparent;
}
```

Comment: Does this solution work ?