# How do I centre a heading (with text and image) to my div?

Tags: html, css

I am very,very new to coding and I am trying to center a heading in a div. I managed to center somehow, but it's not perfectly symmetrical and don't get why. Can anyone help me? Here is my code:

```css
#up {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 100px;
  float: center;
  clear: both;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: powderblue;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}
```

```html
<div id="up">
  <h1 class="arial" align="center" style="color:white"> NOT ANOTHER <img src="logo t shirt.png" style="vertical-align: middle; width:90px; height:90px" ;>T-SHIRT STORE </h1>
</div>
```

Here is how it looks, h1 not symmetrically vertical centred

[image]

Comment: just to know, did you try using `vertical-align`?

Comment: You have fixed height to div. you can give padding top to h1 and make it vertically proper center.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center href and image within div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035498/center-href-and-image-within-div-and-remove-image-border)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `align-items`, `justify-content` properties so just add `display` as `flex` and width to 100% if needed.

> align-items - vertically aligns the flexible container's items when the items do not use all available space on the cross-axis.
>
> justify-content - horizontally aligns the flexible container's items when the items do not use all available space on the main-axis.

Following properties works when display of selected element is flex.

```css
#up {
  width: 100%;
  /*You could even change width to 1200px and it still align the  child element at center of screen*/
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: powderblue;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="up">
  <h1 class="arial" align="center" style="color:white"> NOT ANOTHER <img src="logo t shirt.png" style="vertical-align: middle; width:90px; height:90px" ;>T-SHIRT STORE </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: @Lo Ri Try that using flex.

Comment: Super, frnt! :) This works too! Thanks also for the detailed explaining!

Answer (score 1):

Adding `line-height: 100px` to `#up` solve your problem.

```css
#up {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  float: center;
  clear: both;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: powderblue;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}
```

```html
<div id="up">
  <h1 class="arial" align="center" style="color:white"> NOT ANOTHER <img src="logo t shirt.png" style="vertical-align: middle; width:90px; height:90px" ;>T-SHIRT STORE </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Suuuper, it worked! But I put 95px instead of 100px, to look how I wanted. Thank you, Paolo! :D

Answer (score 0):

add the following attribute in your css.

```
#up{ text-align:center }
```

This will make everything appear in the middle inside that div.

Comment: Thank you or your answer, ashish! I tried it, but still doesn't look like I wanted.