# border-radius creates an outline in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

When border-radius is applied to a coloured div that has a white border, the background color appears outside the white border in corners. Why is this happening in ie? (Tried ie9 and ie10).

```
<div class="rounded"></div>

.rounded {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    background: #f00;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

body {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

The thing here is that I really need the white border, so removing it or making it transparent, as some have proposed, is not an option.
Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z0rt63e2/1/

Comment: can you show us a jsfiddle or a link to the page or something? so that we can see what exaclty it is looking like?

Comment: did you try outline:none css property?

Comment: outline: none has no effect

Comment: No one will probably know *why* this is happening, but it's a good catch and you should notify the [IE dev team](https://connect.microsoft.com/ie/) about it. [Note](http://jsfiddle.net/z0rt63e2/5/) also that the same happens when using an inset box-shadow.

Comment: I don't have IE to test, but have you tried `background-clip: content-box`?

Comment: @disinfor: Yes that seems to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As in my comment above (in the interest of having an answer), use `background-clip: content-box` in your `.rounded` class.

Here's some reading material:
http://www.css3.info/preview/background-origin-and-background-clip/

Comment: Not content-box but padding-box did the trick. You were so close, so I accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @tofu Awesome! I'm glad you got it to work. I remember running into the same problem you had a couple years ago and `content-box` is what did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

according to this post...   [Removing the image border in Chrome/IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013071/removing-the-image-border-in-chrome-ie9)

try,

```
 border-style:none;
```

mayb this helps?

**UPDATE::** I found this link .. http://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/

and according to it(allthe way down at the bottom) we have to add the meta tag..

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

IE=edge  should work and use the latest rendering engine..