# Rounded corner in Chrome - extraneous lines in corners

Tags: html, css, rendering, rounded-corners

I am cracking my head over what causes the extraneous lines that show up around rounded corners in Chrome, IE a Safari. It does not happen in FF.

```css
div.round-box {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

div.round-box .steps {
  background-color: #0fa862;
  border: 20px solid white;
  border-radius: 32px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  top: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-border-radius: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="round-box">
  <a class="steps" href="steps">Follow 5 Easy Steps to Install XYZ</a>
</div>
```

Many thanks for any hints.

[image: Extraneous lines around rounded corners]

Comment: Try This - http://jsfiddle.net/q7h6we32/

Comment: Thank you. Tried it and it fixes the problem in Chrome and Safari. Unfortunatelly it does not seem to do the trick in IE.

Comment: Add `background-clip: padding-box;` to `.steps` - http://jsfiddle.net/L9vf6btu/, check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26468645/border-radius-creates-an-outline-in-ie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a miscalc in the browser render/ anti-aliasing. It's drawing the green background underneath the white border element and a little bit is bleeding out the edge. Can be solved by wrapping the inner element again so the green only draws inside the border.

```css
div.round-box {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
div.inner-box {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 20px solid white;
  border-radius: 32px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 32px;
}
div.round-box .steps {
  display: block;
  background-color: #0fa862;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="round-box">
  <div class="inner-box">
    <a class="steps" href="steps">Follow 5 Easy Steps to Install XYZ</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: At present this is merely a comment on the possible problem. Please adapt the fiddle and test whether your **theory** solves the problem.

Comment: A little terse don't you think @LeeTaylor? We're all just trying to help out here. It's an answer even if i haven't posted a fix yet and really the reason should be more important than a patch so this problem can be avoided in future.

Comment: No, it's a comment! An answer would show a proposed solution, not discuss a **potential** one.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @LeeTaylor, incidentally wrapping it does work and I hope this helps the OP.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking that it must be some rendering / calc problem. Your code (http://jsfiddle.net/94nx6srf/) does not align the adjacent border lines properly, but adding two new CSS properties to the inner-box fixed the problem (http://jsfiddle.net/94nx6srf/1/).  I am going to adopt this solution because it works across all my browsers.

Answer (score 2):

This one is really helpful:
Add `background-clip: padding-box;`
to .steps