# How do I remove the border of a image in Chrome?

Tags: html, css

```css
#test {
  width: 25px;        
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #dddddd;        
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<img src="" alt="" id="test">
```

In Chrome, my image will have border but safari doesn't have.
Is any way can remove it in chrome?

Comment: Check below URL-:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013071/removing-the-image-border-in-chrome-ie9

Answer (score 2):

have you tried adding this to the css?

```
border-style:none;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply removing the src seems to work. If you don't absolutely need the src attribute for what you're working on, taking it out will eliminate the border.

```css
#test {
  width: 25px;        
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #dddddd;        
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<img alt="" id="test">
```

Answer (score 0):

In chrome if browser not find any image it create a default design like that , using image and then use border-style:none; using css.

visit www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-style.asp/