# Why I see the contour of a logo in the navbar on Google Chrome?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating my website and I want to add a log on the navbar.

index.html:

```
<header>
  <div class="header_logo">
    <img class="logo" value="logo"/>
  </div>
  <div>

  </div>
</header>
```

style.css:

```
  .logo
  {
   background-image: url("../icons/car.png");
   border-style: none;
   position: absolute;
   left: 38px;
   top: 19px;
   width: 137px;
   height: 49px;
  }
  .header_logo 
  {
   background-color: #000000;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 75px;
  }
```

the logo is:
[car.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oz80k.png)

But when I test the website it works well on Explorer and Firefox but on Chrome I got a white contour surrounded the logo and the background of the navbar is black.
How can I fix that?

Comment: Can you link the image? It's possible it is the way chrome handles the PNG file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing the image border in Chrome/IE9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013071/removing-the-image-border-in-chrome-ie9)

Comment: @JoshuaPack I edited the question and I added the logo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the PNG file. it looks like it has a white border around it. replace the image with one without a white border and you will be good.

use this file instead
[Car.png](https://i.imgur.com/clprvXh.png)

EDIT: After looking at it, it looks to be an issue with how Chrome works with the `img` tag. just use a `div` tag for it. for example the HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="header_logo">
        <div class="logo" value="logo"></div>
    </div>
    <div>

    </div>
</header>
```

And for the CSS:

```
.logo {
    background-image: url("../icons/car.png");
    border-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 38px;
    top: 19px;
    width: 137px;
    height: 49px;
}
.header_logo {
    background-color: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QpJbwy

If you need to use an `img` tag, you must have a `src` attribute.

Comment: But why in explorer and firefox the white border doesn't appear?

Comment: It is the way transparency PNG is handled by chrome i believe. If you need it to be transparent, you will need to encode it correctly for chrome. I am unsure of the technicality of it.

Comment: I tried the photo that you edited but I got the same thing as before :/

Comment: @xhunter oh wow, that is surprising. Let me draw up a codepen to take a look

Comment: @xhunter ok, i made edits, it is very strange that this happens, but it looks like chrome wants a `src` attribute for `img` tags, so use a `div` tag to work around it. or give it a `src` attribute.