# Remove border on img tag with no src on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have an img tag with no src content:

```
<img class="logo" src="" alt="" />
```

I can't change the src content because it is automatically generated by my company framework.

This is my logo class:

```
.logo {
    background: url('img/logo.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 70%;
    margin-top: 25px;
    border: 0;
    border-style: none;
}
```

But on Chrome, I get this strange border on my image. How can I remove that?

[image: logo with border]

Comment: Some other css class might be adding the border. Try adding important to your border property. `border:0!important;`

Comment: I tried with no success. This is only happening on Chome

Comment: If possible, can you share the URL that has the logo?

Comment: I'm sorry, it is on a local environment

Comment: Using Chrome Dev Tools, you can check the calculated values for the logo element and play with the values to check what causes the border.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013071/removing-the-image-border-in-chrome-ie9
Check out this and try the 2nd answer by Randy. This solved many issues withr andom Borders in Chrome for me. Fooling chrome into thinking there is nothing and use padding to display the content.

Comment: It happens with any replacement for the logo img so it's not dependent on seeing the company logo @ozgur.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the valid way to include an image with no src?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775469/whats-the-valid-way-to-include-an-image-with-no-src)

Answer (score 0):

Might be Outline or box shadow property

Try

```
.logo { 
   outline: none !important;
   box-shadow: none !important
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

```
. logo {
   border: none;
}
```

or

```
. logo {
   border-color: transparent;
}
```

or

```
.logo {
   border: 0px solid transparent;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this answer as a Javascript alternative to css solution (if any)

You can target the `logo` class `img` and change its `src` programmatically. This code should run after the logo has been added to DOM.

```
// Fix the img url here according to your real path    
document.getElementsByClassName[0]("logo").src="img/logo.png";
```

If there are more than one logo class on the page, the code should be modified accordingly though.