# Relatively created button and image causes creating an additional frame for image. Html

Tags: html, css

I cant remove border.

This is my code:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="2:1">
   <mat-grid-tile>
     <button mat-raised-button>1</button>
     <img id="image-diamond"/>
   </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

And css:

```
button{
width: 80%;
height: 70%; 
padding: 20px 40px;
font-size: 32px;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
display: inline-block;
background: linear-gradient(to right, #070600 0%, #f7d931f3 50%, #fae901f3 50%, #f7ef8bf3 100%);
background-size: 200% 100%;
background-position: 100% 0;
transition: background-position 0.3s;
opacity: 70%;
border: 1px solid #f00;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}

#image-diamond{
height: 20%;
width: 10%;
margin-top: 35%;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
right: 5%;
overflow:hidden; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
}
```

And image have additional border. Set background transparent or border nothing change. Set thick on 0px
also does not change anything, and when creating border there second border is still visable, and I can see 2 borders.

[image]

When I set `border: 2px solid red;` I can see white and red border.

[image]

Comment: maby it is the outline. try set the outline to none like this:       outline: none;

Comment: @carlos.gmz Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Comment: if you need to remove the black and red border, then see my solution

Comment: i tested it myself and I dont have a white border. maby change the testing conditions, for example the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change it, that is the default browser behaviour.

Just like when an image has an *invalid* `src` and the browser shows a "broken image" icon, if an image has *no* `src` the browser shows a border to show where the image would be. For more information, see:

- [How can I remove the border around an image without a source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441362/how-can-i-remove-the-border-around-an-image-without-a-source)
- [Strange border on IMG tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743083/strange-border-on-img-tag)

It looks like you want to set a **background image** - to do that, you don't use an `img` element, you can use some other element such as a `div`, e.g.

```
<div class="image-with-background"></div>

.image-background {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-image: url("https://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-600-400-1.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

See the example below:

```css
.empty-img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.image-background {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.background-url {
  background-image: url("https://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-600-400-1.jpg");
}
```

```html
<p>A "broken image" img element with no src: </p>
<img class="empty-img" />

<p>A div element tag with no backgrouund image, but using your background CSS -> no border: </p>
<div class="image-background"></div>

<p>A div element tag with a background image: </p>
<div class="image-background background-url"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this it

```
img {
  text-indent: -999px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried it with `important`, I've been facing similar issue this was how I fixed mine

Comment: It still does not help.

Answer (score 0):

use **border:none;**

in both Like

```
   button{
border:none;
}
    
#image-diamond{
border:none;
}
```

Comment: I was trying everything with border. It isnt border.

Comment: remove border: 1px solid #f00; from button's css and also border:0; then add border:none; it will remove your button border. same thing do with #image-diamond

Comment: this code working fine on using border:none; you can share your html file the problem will be another side of your html

Answer (score 0):

add `border: 0;` and `outline: none;` - (remove black border) in `button` tag to css

```css
button{
width: 80%;
height: 70%; 
padding: 20px 40px;
font-size: 32px;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
display: inline-block;
background: linear-gradient(to right, #070600 0%, #f7d931f3 50%, #fae901f3 50%, #f7ef8bf3 100%);
background-size: 200% 100%;
background-position: 100% 0;
transition: background-position 0.3s;
opacity: 70%;
border: 1px solid #f00;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
border: 0;
outline: none;
}

#image-diamond{
height: 20%;
width: 10%;
margin-top: 35%;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
right: 5%;
overflow:hidden; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="2:1">
   <mat-grid-tile>
     <button mat-raised-button>1</button>
     <img id="image-diamond"/>
   </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: I am trying to remove White border from image. Not from button.

Comment: I extinguished it, it seems - https://ibb.co/JBq3PJz! On a black background. But `border: 0` helps me to remove it!

Comment: You have an idea why for me setting border to 0 does not change anything?

Comment: I can assume that this is a style overlap with a higher priority. Try to put `border: 0!important`. If it doesn't help, then leave a link to the site here..

Comment: ...or maybe it's a pseudo-element `::before` or `::after`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ccwmh7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgrid-list-overview-example.css

Comment: Interface is not extensive, unfortunately I have no experience with html and css but it seems to be some kind of abnormal behavior.

Comment: I was end work yesterday. But FluffyKitten added solution.